# How to notify the use of an event on iPhone. Notification or event in calendar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app needs to notify its user before an event occurs every week. i.e. lesson start.

What is the best way to do this.  Should I create a calendar event from within in the app or should I send a notification every time the event occurs?

The problem is the app might not be running when the event reminder needs to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`UILocalNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this taks, you can set an repeat interval to, for example every week or day.

If you want you could also add an event to the calendar, it really op to you. For this you can use the [`EventKit`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/_index.html).